# Tags in question title auto-search

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, search

When I click "Ask Question" and enter the title, StackOverflow helpfully searches for similar questions. However, it does not take into account the tags field below the question body, and if I put bracketed tags in the title, they're flagged as an error, and not queried.

I can temporarily enter the tag name in the question title itself, but this does not restrict the result set as a proper tag does. I still get results for other languages. Also, if I forget to erase the tag name before posting, I've annoyingly put the language in the question title.

I suggest that the tags field should be joined with the title field when generating the automatic search.

Comment: Holy hell, this is so annoying. Trying to ask a question regarding TypeScript modules and I get Python and filesystem questions suggested. #SixToEightWeeks

Comment: I have come to completely ignore this pane as it is basically useless right now. I was about to ask a question about elastic search and the "Questions that may already have your answer" are about JavaScript, C# LINQ and such. If this pane worked properly, we might receive a lower amount of duplicates...

Comment: Alternatively, you could just search your title first, tags included. However, this completely defeats the entire purpose of the feature... +1

Comment: (About the tags in the titles.) You say ``"I've annoyingly put the language in the question title."`` Why annoyingly? What's wrong with the explicit questions?  Consider ``tags: ansible, python``, and ``title: Show debug msg ...`` Is the question about showing debug msg in Ansible or Python?